# Localhost and port 8080 not opening

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I installed Jenkins on my Amazon EC2. Using Ubuntu, t2 small, my SG `0.0.0.0/0`.  These are the command I run to install jenkins:

```
-sudo apt-get update
-sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
-sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
-wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
-sudo apt-get update
-sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

but my localhost(public ip) :8080 is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Jenkins start successful and the port listen OK on EC2: 
Run:
`netstat -tulon | grep 8080` 
And find 8080 port.

If port 8080 is opened, you need to add Jenkins port in Security Group: add inbound rule allow 8080 port (by default the Security Group inbound rule will disable all access from internet).